# what 'exactness properties' are?

Tags: category-theory

I was just reading the definition of regular category. I cite Borceux, from his Categorical algebra handbook, volume 2:

> Abelian categories are additive, which excludes many interesting situations in which, nevertheless, several "exactness properties" of abelian categories are still valid, like the existence of images. The notion of a regular category recaptures many "exactness properties" of abelian categories, but avoids requiring additivity. For example, the category of sets and most "algebraic-like" categories are regular.

So what I am asking is what are exactness properties, and maybe why the existence of images is one of them.

Comment: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exactness+property

Comment: There isn't an established formal definition for this concept. See [my recent joint paper with Pierre-Alain Jacqmin](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870820305120?dgcid=rss_sd_all) or its [arXiv version](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.02204).